# Why does converting my data into an ndarray give me 'python' terminated by signal SIGBUS (Misaligned address error)?

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error, python-imaging-library

`img` is a PIL Image.  Below is the terminal output when I try to import the data into an ndarray.  Do you think the error is something I did, or something with numpy?

```
>>> img
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=I;16 size=1280x1080 at 0x110CB1560>
>>> img.getdata()
<ImagingCore object at 0x1105df7b0>
>>> np.array(img.getdata(), np.uint16)
fish: Job 1, 'python' terminated by signal SIGBUS (Misaligned address error)
```

Comment: What is your numpy version? or provide your image let us can try it.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, in Python 3.4, Numpy 1.9:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def img_data_in_nd_array():
    img_dir = 'img'
    file_name = 'avatar_physical_attraction.jpg'
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(img_dir, file_name))

    print (img.getdata())
    print (np.array(img.getdata(), np.uint16))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img_data_in_nd_array()
```

Outcome:

```
<ImagingCore object at 0x105b958f0>
[[ 53 152 254]
 [ 53 152 254]
 [ 53 152 254]
 ..., 
 [ 52 151 253]
 [ 52 151 253]
 [ 52 151 253]]
```

Maybe you can provide the image that goes wrong, so we can check whether there is something wrong with that. Have you already tried another image?